# intervention not working on laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

Im trying to

```
$photo = \Image::make($file);
```

did intervention require in composer added two lines to app config.

but i get below error when i upload the pictures

NotSupportedException in Driver.php line 18:
GD Library extension not available with this PHP installation.

after i got that error i did apt-get install php5-gd. and now its installed but still getting error. do i have to set anything in php ini file after i install php5-gd?